# why particles move backwards when camare get close?

Tags: camera, three.js, particle-system

I have a particle system(THREE.JS) with size set to 40 when camera gets close to them they move backwards until they disappear, is that normal how can I change that? I want them to stay still

Comment: Can you setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to show that?

Comment: @mrdoob here you can see the behaviour  http://pruebasmemo.co.nf/ they move when you scroll in

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's because `TrackballControls` is making the camera always looking at the center. So if you zoom in too much you end up with the camera behind the center but still looking at the center.

Comment: Also.. Please, update to r58. We've done some fixes to `TrackballControls`.

Comment: is there a way to avoid that? why does it also happen with flycontrol? thanks @mrdoob